# number of Google Froms Response in one file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

i have a two or more google forms...each of the form response is saved on separate file but i want to save all forms response in one file with different sheets..
plz help me for this...
some of the blogs are suggested to use  **"importRange(key,cells)"**   function for pulling data from outside the our file...
but i thnk its not good trick to save data...
and maximum 50 functions can be used per one file so its not save more than 50 records...
plz help me for solve this problem...

[Copy submitted Form Responses to a New Sheet (PROJECTS) and wanting to be able to edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962809/copy-submitted-form-responses-to-a-new-sheet-projects-and-wanting-to-be-able-t)

this link is copy data script

Answer (score 0):

When a form is created, you can choose the responses destination. Maybe this will help you with what you need.

[image]